# Can Na2S + H2SO4 react to give Na2SO4 + H2O?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Can $\ce{Na2S + H2SO4}$ react to give $\ce{Na2SO4 + H2O}$ or $\ce{Na2O + H2O + SO2}$?

In my textbook, it has been given that the product will be $\ce{NaOH + H2O + SO2}$. Can also the other two products created? If not, then why?

Comment: Your textbook might be incorrect. AFAIR $$\ce{Na2S + H2SO4 -> Na2SO4 + H2S}$$ Were any other reaction conditions mentioned?

Comment: Concentrated acid would have oxidative properties. $\ce{Na2S + 5 H2SO4 -> 2 NaHSO4 + 4 SO2 + 4 H2O}$

Comment: Elemental sulfur could also be a product.

Comment: At least, what is sure is that $\ce{Na2O}$ or $\ce{NaOH}$ will never be produced by action of an acid like $\ce{H2SO4}$ on any sort of substance.

Comment: OP should at least enumerate the considered chemical reactions.

Comment: As Poutnik said, concentrated sulphuric acid is oxidising, dilute sulphuric acid is not. So whether Aniruddha is correct or whether your textbook is accurate here depends on the conditions involved. (The reaction with concentrated sulphuric acid may or may not be complete.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, it is important to understand the nature of this reaction. The reaction here is a redox reaction where one species is oxidised and another species is reduced. In this case, $S^{2-}$ is oxidised to $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ is reduced to $\ce{SO2}$. Hence, even though $\ce{Na2SO4}$ does form (and it usually does since the Sulfide anion is quite basic and would readily accept $\ce{H+}$ from $\ce{H2SO4}$ to form $\ce{HS-}$ or even $\ce{H_2S}$), I believe your textbook is trying to illustrate the redox nature of this reaction.

For the second set, $\ce{Na_2O}$ usually never forms because it is quite reactive and would readily dissolve in water to produce $\ce{NaOH}$. (Usually we would just label this as $\ce{OH- (aq)}$ rather than $\ce{NaOH (aq)}$ because $\ce{Na+}$ is a spectator ion and does not really react.)

Comment: For formatting, See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a more detailed MathJax guide, look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [minor other details](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of excess of $\ce{H2SO4}$, bases like $\ce{Na2O}$ or $\ce{NaOH}$ cannot be produced.

The first mentioned option ( $\ce{Na2SO4 + H2O}$ ) is not possible, as there would be oxidation without reduction. Note that in excess of $\ce{H2SO4}$, $\ce{NaHSO4}$ is formed, not  $\ce{Na2SO4}$

Diluted $\ce{H2SO4}$ would produce $\ce{H2S}$, concentrated one would oxidize sulphides/sulphane, producing $\ce{SO2}$ and/or elementary sulphur.

$$\ce{Na2S + 2 H2SO4 -> H2S + 2 NaHSO4}\tag{1}$$
$$\ce{Na2S + 4 H2SO4 -> S + SO2 + 2 NaHSO4 + 3 H2O }\tag{2}$$

Sulphane reduces sulphur dioxide tu sulphur:

$$\ce{2 H2S + SO2 -> 3 S + 2 H2O}\tag{3}$$

Sulphur can be oxidized as well:

$$\ce{S + 2 H2SO4 -> 3 SO2 + 2 H2O}\tag{4}$$